# Bike engine stops when riding and starts before bike stops

Tags: honda, motorcycle, stall, shine-mc

I have new Honda Shine SP 125cc bike. It traveled near about 100 KM. What I found today, while riding, engine suddenly shut off at low speed and when I press the clutch and release it, engine starts running in the same gear. It happens with me four times continuously in the journey of 3 KM. So I thought it might be the case of Reserve so I turned to Reserve mode of fuel knob. But, it still continue.

Please suggest me possible causes of this situation.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you sure you didn't get some bad gas (like it might have water in it)?